# Swipe back in iOS webview flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, webview, back

in my Flutter app, I use web view. For android, I use willpopscope so when someone presses the back button review page will pop to its previous state.

But in iOS willpopscope is not working, I have tried cupertino_back_gesture package it also not working.

I also tried the gesture detector it works but not working accurately.

is there any solution or any method to do swipe back in flutter iOS web view.

currently i am trying to do this

```
runApp(
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: primaryColor,
    pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      },
    ),
  ),
  home: LocationCheck(),
),
```

);

Comment: Can you share some of the code that is responsible for what you are trying to do?

Comment: `runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: primaryColor,
        pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(
          builders: {
            TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
            TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
          },
        ),
      ),
      home: LocationCheck(),
    ),
  );`

Comment: If you can, it would be best to edit your question and add the code there.